# Are my proofs of the basic order properties of $\mathbb{N}$ correct?

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-number-theory

In Terry Tao's *Analysis I*, the basic properties of order of $\mathbb{N}$ are given, and the proofs are left as an exercise. I have worked through them, but I need someone to check if I'm not deluding myself.

**Properties**:

> 1. $a\ge a$
> 2. If $a \ge b$ and $b \ge c$, then $a \ge c$.
> 3. If $a \ge b$ and $b \ge a$, then $a=b$.
> 4. $a \ge b \iff a+c \ge b+c$
> 5. $a<b \iff S(a) \le b$
> 6. $a<b \iff b = a+d$, where $d>0$

Remarks: $a \ge b \iff a = b+c$ for some natural number $c$, and $a>b \iff a=b+c$, where $a \ne b$. A natural number $a$ is said to be positive if and only if $a \ne 0$. $S(a)$ denotes the successor of $a$. Prior to this, I have proven some basic properties of addition, and only the Peano Axioms were assumed.

**My proofs:**

1. Since $a=a+0$, from our definition, the result follows.
2. Since $a \ge b \iff a=b+d$ for some natural number $d$, and $b \ge c \iff b = c+e$ for some natural number $e$, we have $a=c+(e+d)$, which implies that $a \ge c$.
3. $a \ge b \iff a=b+c$ and $b \ge a \iff b=a+d$, and we have $a=a+(c+d)$; thus by cancellation (which is proved prior to this) we have $c+d =0$, so $c=0$ and $d=0$, and the result follows.
4. If $a \ge b$, then it must be the case that $a=b+c$, where $c$ is a natural number. Now consider $a+c = (b+c)+c$; hence by definition, $a+c \ge b+c$. Now since $a+c \ge b+c$, $a+c = b+c+d$, where $d$ is a natural number, and the result follows.
5. We need to prove that $a < b \implies S(a)+b$ and $S(a)+b \implies a<b$. The first implication can by proven by considering the fact that $c$ must be positive in  $a+c=b$, or else we obtain a contradiction. Now we can write $c$ as $d+1$, where $d$ is a natural number. Hence $a+d+1 = b \iff (a+1)+d = b \iff S(a)+d=b$, and we arrive at our first implication. The second implication can be obtained using a similar argument.
6. We need to prove that $a<b \implies b=a+d$, where $d$ is positive, and $b=a+d \implies a<b$. The first implication follows immediately, since $a \ne b$, or else we obtain a contradiction, and the second can be done in pretty much the same way, but in reverse. But there's something perplexing here, why did this come after (5)? Perhaps there's a simpler proof of (5) without appealing to (6); I'd appreciate it if you could point out how it can be done more simply. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that you’ve proved the properties of addition that you use, it’s mostly right. In the proof of $(4)$, however, you’re using the name $c$ for two different quantities. What you want to say is that if $a\ge b$, then there is a $d$ such that $a=b+d$. But then $a+c=(b+c)+d$, so $a+c\ge b+c$.

For $(5)$, in the right-to-left implication you’re assuming that $S(a)\le b$. From this you can infer that $b=S(a)+c=(a+1)+c=a+(c+1)=a+S(c)$ for some $c$. In order to complete the proof that $a<b$, you must show that $a\ne b$. If $a=b$, then $a+0=a+S(c)$, so (as in the proof of $(3)$) $S(c)=0$, which is impossible. At no point does the proof of either direction actually use $(6)$; rather, the proofs use the definitions of $\le$ and $<$.

There’s no real need for $(6)$ to follow $(5)$; indeed, it could have come very early in the list, except that Tao seems to have decided to put all of the results strictly about $\le$ before those involving $<$.